# Resharper - wrapping long lines with continuation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, configuration, editor, resharper

I'm using Resharper 8. ( visual studio 2010).

I've enabled "wrap long lines"

[image]

Bu when I have long lines it does wrap them but it starts at `"X=0"` at the next line ( see number "2" :  )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfdz3.png
[image]

Question :

Is there any configuration ( VS || R#) so that when `1` is wrapped , `2` will start under `3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to ReSharper. This is how Visual Studio handles wrapping long lines - it's still a single line of text, as you can see by the line number, but it's wrapped to all appear on the screen at once.

If you want to reformat the text, you can simply enter a carriage return, e.g. after the `if` statement, and the text will then move to a new line and should be indented under your number 3. ReSharper can do this for you with code cleanup (ReSharper -> Tools -> Code cleanup)

Comment: Visual Studio will always *wrap* at x=0, but adding a new line should insert an indent, as long as there's room. Is the file part of a project? A .cs file? What does ReSharper's code cleanup do?